# Incorrect Typing of React Hook with Firestore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a custom hook for querying a specific Firebase Firestore collection/document.

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { FirebaseContext } from 'providers/Firebase/FirebaseContextProvider';

const useFireStore = (
  collection: string,
  doc: string,
  loadingDelay: number = 0,
) => {
  const { firestore } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [document, setDocument] = useState<
    firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined
  >();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setDocument(undefined);
    const docRef = firestore.collection(collection).doc(doc);
    docRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        setDocument(doc.data());
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        }, loadingDelay);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        setError(e);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [collection, loadingDelay, doc, firestore]);

  return [document, loading, error];
};

export default useFireStore;
```

I use it like this:

```
const [details, loading, error] = useFireStore('listDetails', `${id}`, 300);
```

When I mouse over `document` in `const [document, setDocument] = useState` in the hook, I see that the `document` type will be:

`const document: firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined`

However, when I mouse over `document` in `const [details, loading, error] = ...` in the component, I see the possible types as:

`const details: boolean | firebase.firestore.DocumentData | null | undefined`

Where is this possible `boolean` or `null` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by typing the return of the `useFireStore` hook such as:

```
const useFireStore = (
  collection: string,
  doc: string,
  loadingDelay: number = 0,
): [firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined, boolean, Error | null] => {
...
}
```